# How to redirect to an external domain in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I need to redirect back to an external url after completing an action in my flask application.
The code looks like this

```
if form.next.data is not None:
    return redirect(form.next.data)
```

where `form.next.data` can be an absolute url for an external domain like "www.google.com". However on passing the next value as an external url, this redirect is instead redirecting to `http://mysitename/www.google.com` and failing with a 404.

How do I specify that the redirect is to an external domain and stop Flask from appending it to my domain root?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you need to append a prefix `http://` or `https://` to `"www.google.com"`. Otherwise Flask is treating that as a relative url inside app.
So below will be a 404 as it's going to "localhost:5000/www.google.com"

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return redirect("www.google.com")
```

But if you try with `http://`, it should work fine.

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return redirect("http://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you append "http://" in front of the url before passing it in redirect.

```
s = form.next.data
if s is not None:
    if s.find("http://") != 0 and s.find("https://") != 0:
        s = "http://" + s
    return redirect(s)
```