# How to permanently redirect all pages of a subdomain to a sub-path of the www domain?

Tags: redirect, flask, url-rewriting, dns, cname

I have this website for instance:

- https://www.neuraxle.neuraxio.com/stable/index.html

I still host that old site but I moved it here:

- https://www.neuraxio.com/en/neuraxle/stable/index.html

I'd like each old page to point to each new page. A permanent redirect like this:

`https://www.neuraxle.neuraxio.com/* ==> https://www.neuraxio.com/en/neuraxle/*`

Do I need to host a server for this to manually writing a Python Flask app that redirects each URL with a custom rewrite? I'd like to avoid coding this by using DNS. Is there a DNS trick I can use? I use GoDaddy to manage my DNS.

*Optional: if there is nothing to be done with DNS, can you provide an example Flask URL handler method? Is there a free hosting service available for me to host this flask app?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked, accepted bountied answer is poor:

```
@app.before_request
def redirect_to_new_domain():
    FROM_DOMAINS = ['0.0.0.0:' + str(PORT), 'https://www.neuraxio.com', 'www.neuraxio.com', "neuraxio.com"]
    SUBPATH = "/en/neuraxle"
    TO_DOMAIN = 'www.neuraxle.org'
    urlparts = urlparse(request.url)
    print(urlparts, urlparts.netloc)
    if urlparts.netloc in FROM_DOMAINS and SUBPATH in urlparts.path:
        parsed = urlparts
        parsed = parsed._replace(netloc=TO_DOMAIN)
        parsed = parsed._replace(path=urlparts.path.replace(SUBPATH, ""))
        return redirect(parsed.geturl(), code=301)
```

Note: my own answer here doesn't completely answer the original question but at least compiles. We also needed this as I answer now, to the exception that we we also have a sub-path to redirect from instead of to.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to redirect, using `RewriteEngine` and `.htaccess` file you should have in your web root or accessible via your hosting control panel, using regular expressions. I got a little unsure about direction of move due to your wording, so just in case, here are both directions with some references.

If you want to redirect from [subdomain to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory) (which seems more likely as per your example) you can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.neuraxle\.neuraxio.\com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/neuraxle
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/neuraxle/$1 [L,NC]
```

If you want to redirect from [folder to subdomain](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/08/redirecting-from-subdirectory-to-subdomain-using-htaccess/), you can do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.neuraxio.com
RewriteRule ^en/neuraxle/(.*)$ http://www.neuraxle.sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Some additional references:

- Apache mod_rewrite [Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- Apache mod_rewrite [Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

**Edit:** on another thought it depends on deployment option/platform you have used which you haven't mentioned in your question.

And actually, on yet another thought, GoDaddy indeed allows a DNS redirect. Go to 
[image: Domain manager -> DNS -> DNS Management]
And near the bottom of the page on the right there will be forwarding section:
[image]

In the SUBDOMAIN enter: `www.neuraxle` and in the FORWARD TO select `https://` and enter `www.neuraxio.com/en/neuraxle/` and this should do the trick. I'll keep `mod_rewrite` info just in case.

Comment: Is that a PHP server with cPanel? What kind of server is that precisely?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is available in web servers (`Apache` and `nginx` are most common) and if you are using a shared hosting the access to their configuration might be via an `.htaccess` file in the `public_html` or similar named web root folder or, via control panel of the hosting (of which `cPanel` is the most common one). If you are NOT using ANY web server but serving from flask directly, `mod_rewrite` might still be an option https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/cgi/

Comment: Your DNS solution doesn't work and seem to have broken the site. Try to visit https://www.neuraxle.neuraxio.com/ for instance.

Comment: If by "have broken the site" you meant the browser message about connection not being private, you have to fix you SSL certificate to cover all of the subdomains - a wildcard certificate as described here, for example: https://ca.godaddy.com/help/what-is-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-567 Otherwise, the site works fine for me when I bypass the warning about not private connection

Comment: Would there be a way to avoid buying wildcard certificates all along?

Comment: To avoid browser security alerts, you either have to buy a wildcard or a multidomain certificate or two certificates: https://serverfault.com/questions/566426/does-each-subdomain-need-its-own-ssl-certificate, alternatively you can stop using SSL altogether and switch to HTTP, lastly you can find a free option (I've used StartSSL before): https://geekflare.com/free-ssl-tls-certificate/

Answer (score 1):

**This should be of help out.**

Sometimes you need to write a website that simply redirects from one domain to another. For example, you might have created a website at yourusername.pythonanywhere.com, and it's become popular enough that you decided to upgrade to a paid plan and host it on www.yourdomain.com -- but there are lots of links out there that go to the old domain, and you want them to continue working.

The best solution is to have a simple website running at yourusername.pythonanywhere.com which, when it receives a request, redirects the user to the new domain -- so requests to http://yourusername.pythonanywhere.com/something are redirected automatically to http://www.yourdomain.com/something, and so on.

To do this, you need to have a website on the "Web" tab for both domains; the one on www.yourdomain.com is your main site, and the one on yourusername.pythonanywhere.com is a simple Flask app using Python 3.6, with the following code in the flask_app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request

app = Flask(__name__)

from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

FROM_DOMAIN = "yourusername.pythonanywhere.com"
TO_DOMAIN = "www.yourdomain.com"

@app.before_request
def redirect_to_new_domain():
    urlparts = urlparse(request.url)
    if urlparts.netloc == FROM_DOMAIN:
        urlparts_list = list(urlparts)
        urlparts_list[1] = TO_DOMAIN
        return redirect(urlunparse(urlparts_list), code=301)
```

**OR TRY THE BELOW METHOD**

[How to redirect to an external domain in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343254/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-domain-in-flask)

Comment: This seems like it would work. Would it work for a deep page like this one also: `https://www.neuraxle.neuraxio.com/something/something.html` redirect to `https://www.neuraxio.com/en/neuraxle/something/something.html`

Comment: It isn't near to work. I accepted bounty as it was the deadline.